# Capture debug window output in a unit test?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, xctest

I'm writing some utility code to print statistics to stdout if the command-line app is invoked with a given parameter, `--static`. Right now I'm simply using `print` and string interpolation (which is great!).

It seems like this is something I should put into my unit tests as well.

Is there an easy way *in the test code*, to redirect the output to a string, or otherwise capture it so I can `XCTAssertEqual` against it?

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting output is not the way you would do it in unit-testing.  Instead, you have some alternative options:

- You could have a helper function like `generateStatistics` which produces a string which is then printed.  In unit-testing you would not test the printing part.  Instead, you only test if the function `generateStatistics` provides the correct result string.  The printing part you can then test in integration testing.
- You could mock the print function, that is, replace it by a function that, instead of printing the strings, collects them and allows them to be analysed by your test code.  I am not familiar with swift and so I cannot tell you if you can easily mock `print` directly - if not, you could wrap it with some other function that you can mock.

On a side note: You mentioned that your option is `--static`, but I assume you meant `--statistic`, right?